# Replace <li> with Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

in my master page. Origninal I had the code:

```
<ul> 
   <li>Home</li> 
   <li>About</li> 
   <li>Sermon</li> 
</ul>
```

In my MVC 2 project, I want to use Html.ActionLink to replace li etc.
So my code:

```
          <div id="leftcolumn">
               <% @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", "Home") %> 
               <% @Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home") %>
               <% @Html.ActionLink("Sermon", "Sermon", "Home") %>
          </div>
```

The snapshot likes:
[image: MVC]

Please correct my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `@`, since this is not a `razor` view (MVC 3). In MVC 2 you do:

```
<div id="leftcolumn">
       <%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", "Home") %> 
       <%= Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home") %>
       <%= Html.ActionLink("Sermon", "Sermon", "Home") %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I nest it with the code? <div id="leftcolumn">
                  <li> <%=Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home") %></li> 
                  <li> <%=Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home") %></li>
                  <li>  <%=Html.ActionLink("Sermon", "Sermon", "Home") %></li> li is within div section.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to mix the Razor view engine syntax with the classic view engine syntax. If you're truly using MVC 2, you're not using Razor so your code should probably be:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Home","Home","Home") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mixing Razor syntax (MVC3) with MVC2 code, for MVC2 you want to do:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", "Home") %>
...
```